# Using mono to generate classes for a database

Tags: database, mono

So I found a tutorial on how to generate a class for my database. I installed Mono for windows, I got DbLinq and Npgsql, but i'm having a slight problem understanding how to generate the class.

The tutorial says I should use this in mono

```
mono DbMetal.exe /conn:"server=localhost;user id=user;\
password=password; database=db" /provider=PostgreSQL \
/code:db.cs /pluralize
```

If I write that into Mono i get this message

```
Reading schema from DBML file '\'
DbMetal : Access to the Path '\' is denied
```

What path should be there? The tutorial doesn't specify.

Here is the tutorial : http://romain.blogreen.org/blog/2009/07/linq-postgresql-and-mono/

What should I do to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I tried the same thing a few months ago, and was later convinced by the folks on the mono mailinglist that the whole ling2sql/dbmetal thing is pretty much broken. I decided to switch NHibernate (with FluentNhibernate) and saved me a lot of headache.

Comment: As @user1039462 mentioned, you should avoid using LINQ to SQL. There was a decision from Microsoft that LINQ to SQL was a dead end, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/10/31/clarifying-the-message-on-l2s-futures.aspx and it is right now. NHibernate was the only alternative in the past, but now Microsoft releases Entity Framework as a true open source project, so that you might use EF too, http://entityframework.codeplex.com/

Comment: in the end i managed to make LINQ to SQL work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows/.NET, you are supposed to use SqlMetal,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386987.aspx

According to DbMetal's page, it is an equivalent of SqlMetal,

http://code.google.com/p/dblinq2007/wiki/DbMetal

The article you followed was written from Mono/Linux, so it may not demonstrate what are the parameters you should use on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows, why use Mono? Test with .NET first, and if that works but Mono doesn't, file a bug.

Also, I wouldn't be surprised that some things may fail on Mono for Windows. Mono is better supported in non-Windows platforms (because that's the main reason for its existence).